# ImporError: No module named 'SimpleXMLRPCServer'

Tags: python-3.x, xmlrpclib

I was trying to get on hands with frozen astropy. But when I try to install it it gives

**ImporError:  No module named 'SimpleXMLRPCServer'**

I also tried to install using pip, but it shows:

**Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xmlrpclib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for xmlrpclib**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SimpleXMLRPCServer module has been merged into xmlrpc.server standard module in Python3. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.server.html)

Just do "from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer"